# Rails render status: :not found missing template error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering

While developing an app for a course,I hit upon a stumbling block:

[The error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRfJi.png)

And here is my  Stocks Controller error, where the error appears:

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController
  def search
    if params[:stock]
      @stock = Stock.find_by_ticker(params[:stock])
      @stock ||= Stock.new_from_lookup(params[:stock])
    end

    if @stock
      render json: @stock
      #render partial: 'lookup'

    else
      render status: :not_found ,nothing: true
    end

  end

end
```

On the course, they have the same code as I do,but for them, it works.The only difference I am aware of is that they are working on Rails 4(Nitrous),and that I am working on Rails 5(Mac OS X/Atom IDE/GitLab repository).Please help me if you can!Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`:nothing` option is [deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/1099329be081297c16b02141ec13ca6a05ff037c/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb#L101) and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use `head` method to respond with empty response body.

Try this:

```
render body: nil, status: :not_found
```

or:

```
head :not_found
```

<sub>Please don't post errors as images, copy-past the text</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are not rendering `json` in else clause and hence Rails for looking for a HTML view which is not present. To fix this, update the code something as below:

```
class StocksController < ApplicationController
  def search

    if params[:stock]
      @stock = Stock.find_by_ticker(params[:stock])
      @stock ||= Stock.new_from_lookup(params[:stock])
    end

    if @stock
      render json: @stock
      #render partial: 'lookup'

    else
      render :json => {:error => "not-found"}.to_json, :status => 404
    end 

  end

end
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution as well, it works splendidly!